# How to interpret CAPM model?

Tags: capm, fama-french

I want to run CAPM model on two portfolios P1 and P2.  Where CAPM  is Rt - Rft = λ0 + λ1 (Rmt - Rft)
Results which I got:
Portfolios  Intercept   Coefficient of Rm-Rf    Adjusted R2
P1  0 i.e not sig. value    significant 29%
P2  not zero i.e sig. value significant 85%

For the P1 intercept is zero, is this mean CAPM is best model for P1 as it is capable of capturing the variation in the returns. But if we consider adj. R2 it only 29% which is very low which mean this model explain only 29% variation in returns of P1.
For P2 intercept is not zero as it is significant, is this mean that this model is not best for P2 as its intercept is not zero. But it has adj. R2 value of 85% which very high in comparision of P1. 
•   How do I interpret these results? CAPM is best for which portfolio? 
•   Should I consider either intercept or adj. R2?
•   Should I consider both of them. But if I consider both of them, then these results are contradictory.
Kindly help me. 
Thank you
Priya

Comment: CAPM should not-reject the hypotesis of intercept = 0. Otherwise it means there are other effects not captured in your CAPM world. The fact that the second portfolio has opposite characteristics simply confirms you need to consider other factors. Statistically speaking, better a less powerful but correct model (i.e. lower R2 but 0 intercept) that a more powerful but wrong.

Comment: P1: intercept is zero and adj R2 is 29%. P2: intercept is not zero and adj R2 is 85%. This line is not clear in my original post.

Comment: @Vitomir sir, you mean Capm is good for P1 but less powerful and correct model. for P2 Capm is not correct model but powerful. is this mean in a factor model of asset pricing it is intercept which has more importance and yes of course significant coefficients but R2 does not matter?

Comment: Correct first part. Second part it is not about thr importantance of. Intercept  rather the importance of the assumptions. These are statistical models brigdging towards economics. Assumptions must hold for the model. To make sense. In fact, I suggest you to model diagnose the residuals and try some factor extension, such as Fama French

Comment: I have compared CAPM, 3f, 4f and 5f model and created 25 dependent portfolios i.e 5*5 sorting based on size-b/m ratio. I found that in CAPM out of 25 only one intercept is not zero and R2 is small. in 3f model of ff three out 25 intercepts are significant but R2 values has been increased a lot if compare with capm. 4f and 5f model does not show any improvement over three factor model. I have also check GRS test , which also support for 3f model. so, should I conclude that 3f model is best over capm? and 4f and 5f model are not good. and sir what you mean by diagnose residuals. thanks

Comment: Yes good you can conclude that. Refer to literature related to Fama and French model and especially to the one addressing their tests (both cross sectional and time dimensional). By diagnose residuals I mean that you should make sure also the residuals behave according to the model assumptions (thus I guess iid normal mean 0, var 1)